# Roblox Place-to-place teleport problems

Tags: lua, roblox

I am creating a script that due to a condition(if), it will teleport the player to another place.

The language is **RBXLua**.

Here is the script:

```
----------
tex = "rbxassetid://1655327330"
x = math.random(10)
lg = game.lighting
pitch = 1
negpos = 0
player = game.Players:GetChildren()
z = 0
ys = 0
w = 0

----------
if x < 1 then
lg.Sky.SkyboxBk = tex
lg.Sky.SkyboxDn = tex
lg.Sky.SkyboxFt = tex
lg.Sky.SkyboxUp = tex
lg.Sky.SkyboxLf = tex
lg.Sky.SkyboxRt = tex
while true do
lg.FogEnd = lg.FogEnd - 1
if lg.FogEnd < 2 then
    game:GetService("TeleportService"):Teleport(1825330145, { player })
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

game.Players:GetChildren() will give you a table of all players (Player-instances). 
Your code actually looks like this:

```
game:GetService("TeleportService"):Teleport(1825330145, { Player })
```

If this is a LocalScript, you can simply do game.Players.LocalPlayer to access the player-instance. If it's a server script however, you need to either do game.Players:GetPlayers() and access the first index of that table, or you need to send all players to that place.

To loop through all players in a place, you can make use of the in-pairs loop.

```
for index, player in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
   print("Player's name is", player.Name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still obtaining the "Unable to cast value to Object" error even after doing so. I don't understand what the "Object" is, it may be helpfull knowing so.

Comment: Hi! Could you show us the current code? Update your original post with it, and I'll take a look.